# Can I make an object method that will modify itself if called alone but return a new object if called during copy initialization?

Tags: c++, methods, copy-constructor

I'm writing a custom datetime class. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
datetime mydate;
mydate.to_utc();  // object modifies itself
```

but when called like this:

```
datetime mynewdate = mydate.to_utc();
```

or like this:

```
datetime mynewdate(mydate.to_utc());
```

I do not want mydate.to_utc() to modify itself, just to initialize/construct mynewdate with value of mydate.to_utc();

Thanks,

Comment: This is a bad idea and a surprising API. Choose one or the other.

Comment: Should really be two functions, as generally to_*** style functions don't modify the object they are invoked upon.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo could you explain why this is not a good idea? What would be a better way?

Comment: Note that in `mydate.to_utc();  // object modifies itself` you'll probably always want to include that comment in order not to surprise the reader. In which case `mydate = mydate.to_utc()` without comment actually conveys the same message, _and_ leaves you with a consistent interface (_and_ is actually shorter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with others that it's a generally bad idea to mix an API like that, there's a simple way to solve it anyway: Make the non-returning function not return anything (of course) and make the returning function `const` qualified. Member function `const` qualification is part of the function signature, and can be used to distinguish between overloads.

Something like this:

```
class datetime
{
public:
    // ...

    // This function modifies the current object in place
    void to_utc();

    // This function returns a new datetime object
    datetime to_utc() const;
};
```

Code similar to the above is not uncommon for "setters" and "getters", but then the compiler have the added luxury of being able to distinguish between the "setter" and the "getter" by arguments as well (the "setter" have an argument, the "getter" doesn't).

This difference between "setters" and "getters" and the above code, is (as mentioned) that the compiler could differentiate between a "setter" and a "getter" through the arguments. This is not possible to do with my above solution to the problem being asked about. And could lead to build errors, as mentioned in a comment. The solution provided could work in some situations but not in others, so care should be taken when using it.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted as it answered the question succinctly. However, given the above answers I think I will not use it and choose a different API design!

Comment: Problematic... `datetime dt0; datetime dt1 = dt0.to_utc();` – as dt0 is not const, it would select the self-modifying overload, which according to question isn't desired. And as this overload doesn't have a return value, code wouldn't even compile... So we'd need to apply a `const_cast` to dt0 before. Would that still be in the sense of the question?

Answer (score 2):

What I generally end up doing is to provide two function:

```
struct datetime
{
    // mutate the object itself
    void apply_to_utc();

    // return the new object
    auto to_utc() const -> datetime;

};
```

This makes it much clearer which function is called and what is the intent of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

What you intend to realise is not possible with the means of C++: Overload resolution is completely independent of return type – and of this one being evaluated or not.

So these two different overloads

```
void to_utc();     // self-modifying
datetime to_utc(); // returning new object
```

will always remain ambiguous.

Now you *could* try to make them distinguishable by making one of them const (as [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57324909/1312382)), but that will not have the effect you are after:

```
datetime dt0;
datetime dt1 = dt0.to_utc();
```

`dt0` is not const, so overload resolution would select the non-const overload as well, and you'd end up in `dt0` modifying itself again. Even worse: As the selected overload returns `void`, code wouldn't even compile. You now could resolve that by casting appropriately:

```
datetime dt1 = const_cast<datetime const>(dt0).to_utc();
```

I have quite some doubts, though, if this is yet in the sense of the question...

What effectively remains is renaming one of the two overloads:

```
void to_utc();           // self-modifying
datetime as_utc() const; // creating a copy
//                ^^^^^
// independent from given problem: the function won't modify 'this' object
// so having it const still is a good idea...
```

or you have one of the overloads as a free-standing (or static; I'd prefer the former, though) function, e. g.:

```
datetime to_utc();

void to_utc(datetime&);
```

I personally would remain with the two member functions of different name, though...